# codeception - transfer variable in executeInSelenium method

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Codeception have a method, which executes selenium functions. I need to transfer an variable with sitename inside a function, which executes this method, so my code

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function(\WebDriver $webdriver) {
  $webdriver->get('http://google.com');
});
```

might look like this:

```
$I->goToSite('http://google.com');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I must have missed the articles about the PHP's closures.
so, from `PHP 5.3` I can do this using closures:

```
$I->executeInSelenium(function(\WebDriver $webdriver) use ($url) {
$webdriver->get($url);
});
```

But this need is going to be deprecated, because from Codeception 2.0.6 method `AmOnPage()` (and from 2.0.7 - `AmOnUrl()`) accepts absolute URL's.